# Galen framework for automated responsive testing

Tags: responsive-design, automated-tests, galen

I want to automate responsive testing of web page and as I was searching what would be the best solution I saw that a lot of answers were referring to Galen framework. I started to search for some tutorials, articles or code examples for this framework, but all the data I found was from 2013-2015, not newer, so I am afraid that it is a little bit outdated framework. Is anyone still using Galen framework for automating responsive testing, and if yes - would you recommend it?
If not - do you maybe have suggestion for some alternative that has more up to date documentation?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.